# Git Editor when commiting vim

Tags: git

when I enter `git commit -a` in Git Bash, the editor appears. When enter esc, the screen blinks, but I do not leave. I tried all the other commands from [git commit -a confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164874/git-commit-a-confusion), but I cannot leave.
If I close the editor and reopen the bash, all the commands in the cash went (with top arrow) and also the pointer to the working directory is destroyed.

Is it possible to use `git commit -a <filename>` and then push ? I will set git to write a default msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a message with `-m`:

```
git commit -m "Some commit message"
```

Or change your editor to something you find easier to use:

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Or with vi, just hit `O`, type your message, hit `<esc>`and then `:wq`.

Comment: I prefer the `O` , a big O from the alphabet and to save the file I prefer the shortcut `x` in `vim` instead of `wq`..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `git config --global core.editor "vim"`

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the vim setting as `git editor`. Please check the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173440/1705829) for a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).